# Getting inserted ID after INSERT ... SELECT on Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring, jdbc, insert, ora-00933

This SQL statement works if I run it from my Oracle client (SQL Developer):

```
insert into Person (Name) select 'Bob' from dual
```

It also works if I issue it via Spring JDBC, without using a [KeyHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/KeyHolder.html):

```
final PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator() {

    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
        throws SQLException
    {
        return con.prepareStatement(
                "insert into Person (Name) select 'Bob' from dual");
    }
};
jdbcOperations.update(psc);
```

However I need to use a KeyHolder in order to get the ID of the newly inserted row. If I alter the above code to use a KeyHolder as follows:

```
final KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
final PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator() {

    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
        throws SQLException
    {
        return con.prepareStatement(
            "insert into Person (Name) select 'Bob' from dual",
            new String[] {"PersonID"});
    }
};
jdbcOperations.update(psc, keyHolder);
```

... then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:842)
    at au.com.bisinfo.codecombo.logic.ImportServiceImpl.insertLoginRedirectRule(ImportServiceImpl.java:107)
    at au.com.bisinfo.codecombo.logic.ImportServiceImpl.runImport(ImportServiceImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy8.runImport(Unknown Source)
    at au.com.bisinfo.codecombo.ui.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:844)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
    ... 15 more
```

FWIW, everything's fine if I do an INSERT ... VALUES instead of an INSERT ... SELECT (although this doesn't help me, as I need to select things):

```
final KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
final PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator() {

    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
        throws SQLException
    {
        return con.prepareStatement(
            "insert into Person (Name) values ('Bob')",
            new String[] {"PersonID"});
    }
};
jdbcOperations.update(psc, keyHolder);
```

I'm using:

- Spring JDBC 3.0.3.RELEASE
- JDBC driver: ojdbc6.jar version 11.2.0.1.0
- RDBMS: Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.5.0 - Production
- commons-dbcp 1.4

N.B. my app needs to use standard SQL in order to remain db-neutral, which rules out any Oracle-specific SQL (I won't be selecting from "dual" in real life).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String, int)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)) interface is clear

> Creates a default PreparedStatement object that has the capability **to retrieve auto-generated keys**

So you are using The wrong method. Try

```
return con.prepareStatement(
        "insert into Person (Name) select 'Bob' from dual",
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

instead

Comment: That method is one of three that can return the generated keys, the other two being prepareStatement(String, int[]) and prepareStatement(String, String[]). I'm using the latter, which IME is the right one for Oracle. Still, I'll try your suggestion and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Andrew Swan You are right. Thank you! But let me know The output

Answer (score 1):

I suspect using a KeyHolder with an INSERT SELECT statement isn't and won't be supported because the select could theoretically select multiple rows, and if it did there would be no way to return those multiple keys into a single KeyHolder. For what you are trying to accomplish, it will likely be easier to simply use a select statement followed by an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
INSERT INTO blah b (blah1, blah2, blah3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?) RETURNING b.id INTO ?";
```

Comment: I can't use INSERT ... VALUES because I need to select stuff. Also I don't want to use RETURNING .. INTO because AFAIK it's Oracle-specific.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't supported by Oracle JDBC Driver

Comment: That's what I'm guessing; do you have a reference for this?